# Set object property in an array true/false, whether the id matches with any id from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

So first, here's a simple snippet to demonstrate what I mean exactly, and what I have tried.

```js
let array_1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Peter'   },
    { id: 2, name: 'John'    },
    { id: 3, name: 'Andrew'  },
    { id: 4, name: 'Patrick' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Brian'   }
];

let array_2 = [
    { id:  1, name: 'not Peter'   },
    { id: 80, name: 'not John'    },
    { id:  3, name: 'not Andrew'  },
    { id: 40, name: 'not Patrick' },
    { id:  5, name: 'not Brian'   }
];

array_1.forEach(item_1 => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++) {
        item_1.matches = array_2[i].id === item_1.id
    }
});

console.log('matched_array', array_1);
```

The goal here is to add the `matches` property to each object in `array_1` and set it to `true`/`false`, based on whether the `id` matches with any other `id` from `array_2`.

In this current example, the result of the `matches` properties should go like this: `true - false - true - false - true`. But my current code only sets this property correctly in the last element of the array (`array_1`).
Obviously it's because my code is not entirely correct, and that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first create one object with `reduce` method that you can then use as a hash table to check if the element with the same id exists in the array 2.

```js
let array_1=[{"id":1,"name":"Peter"},{"id":2,"name":"John"},{"id":3,"name":"Andrew"},{"id":4,"name":"Patrick"},{"id":5,"name":"Brian"}, {"id":6,"name":"Joe"}]
let array_2=[{"id":1,"name":"not Peter"},{"id":80,"name":"not John"},{"id":3,"name":"not Andrew"},{"id":40,"name":"not Patrick"},{"id":5,"name":"not Brian"}]

const o = array_2.reduce((r, e) => (r[e.id] = true, r), {})
const result = array_1.map(e => ({ ...e, matches: o[e.id] || false}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This works fine, and although I did make them the same lenght in the snippet, but I noticed this doesn't work once the length of `array_1` is more than that of `array_2`. Adding one more object already throws an error.

In reality, these two arrays don't necessary share the same lenght, and while I didn't think it would count, it apparently does. Can you maybe edit it so that it works that way too?

Comment: I'm starting to feel bad, it seems like I'm nitpicking and I'm sorry, but I also just noticed, after trying to implement this code, that it seems like it only sets the `matches` property to `true`, if the 2 objects are at the same `index`. Swap the `id` of 'Peter'(1) and 'John'(2), and Peter's `matches` property already sets to `false`, even though `array_2`˙does contain an object with the `id` of 1. It should be working with completely randomized arrays for me. I really didn't know such minor details count this much.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Works perfectly now, although I have no idea how it works( I don't really understand what's happening in the code), but it does the job.

Comment: You can check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce. It iterates through array 1 and for each element it sets key-value pair on the accumulator object where the key is the current element id and the value is just true. Then we use this object inside the map method to check if the id of the current element in array 2 exists in previously created object or we set the value of matches to false.

Answer (score 1):

I would first collect the ids of `array_2` in a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), sets have a O(1) lookup time so checking if an id is in this set is fast. Then iterate over `array_1` and check if the id is present in the created set using [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

```js
let array_1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Peter'   },
    { id: 2, name: 'John'    },
    { id: 3, name: 'Andrew'  },
    { id: 4, name: 'Patrick' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Brian'   }
];

let array_2 = [
    { id:  1, name: 'not Peter'   },
    { id: 80, name: 'not John'    },
    { id:  3, name: 'not Andrew'  },
    { id: 40, name: 'not Patrick' },
    { id:  5, name: 'not Brian'   }
];

const array_2_ids = new Set(array_2.map(item_2 => item_2.id));
array_1.forEach(item_1 => item_1.matches = array_2_ids.has(item_1.id));

console.log('matched_array', array_1);
```

---

Your current code doesn't work because the for-loop will update the `item_1.matches` property for each element in `array_2`. This means you are overwriting the property each time. This in turn will effectivly result in `item_1` only being checked against the last item in `array_2`.

To make your code work this:

> ```
> array_1.forEach(item_1 => {
>     for (let i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++) {
>         item_1.matches = array_2[i].id === item_1.id
>     }
> });
> ```

Should be changed into this:

```
array_1.forEach(item_1 => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++) {
        if (array_2[i].id === item_1.id) {
            item_1.matches = true;
            return;
        }
    }
    item_1.matches = false;
});
```